# Proving a geometric inequality $BE+CF>EF$

Tags: geometry, triangle-inequality

In the figure $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $\Delta EDF$ is right triangle.Prove that $BE+CF>EF$

[image]

I tried triangle inequality $$BE+ED>BD$$
$$CD+FC>DF$$
Add:$$BE+FC>DF-ED$$

I am stuck now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Rotate the figure by $180^\circ$ around $D$.

Now the desired inequality becomes $BE + BF' > EF$.

However $EF = EF'$ by congruent triangles $\triangle EDF' \cong \triangle EDF$.

Finish off using triangle inequality.

Comment: Oops, it seems that I only need to rotate $\triangle CDF$. The rest of the figure does nothing except being aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: That was very clever!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Draw $\triangle DEG \cong \triangle DEB$ ($DG = DB, EG = BE$)

Then $\angle GDF = 90^0 - \angle EDG = 90^0 - \angle BDE = \angle FDC$

Also, $ DG = DB = DC$.

So $\triangle DFG \cong \triangle DFC$ (by S-A-S, $DF$ is common).

So $GE + GF \gt EF \implies BE + CF \gt EF$.

Comment: Nice proof by reflection/folding.

Comment: @player3236 thank you! I like your solution quite a bit. I was wondering how you drew so fast and answered. It would take me forever to draw the diagram itself :)

Comment: I have been using GeoGebra nonstop in teaching for the past year due to current events, or rather, *event*.

Comment: Nice proof (+1)

Comment: @Angelo thank you!